# Forcing an AsyncStream[A] into a Seq[A] in scala

Tags: scala, twitter-util

I am specifically using twitter's AsyncStream and I need to take the results of concurrent processing, and make it into a Seq, but the only way I've managed to get working is horrendous. This feels like it should be a one liner, but all my attempts with Await and force have either hung or not processed the work.

Here's what I have working - what's a more idiomatic way of doing this?

```scala
  def processWork(work: AsyncStream[Work]): Seq[Result] = {
    // TODO: make less stupid
    val resultStream = work.flatMap { processWork }
    var results : Seq[Result] = Nil
    resultStream.foreach {
      result => {
        results = results :+ result
      }
    }
    results
  }
```

Comment: `foreach` is an `action` which will bring all of your data in `driver node` for processing. Why don't you use `lazy transformation` `map` instead of `foreach`?

Comment: is `Await.result(work.toSeq(), 1.second)` hanging on you with the imports `import com.twitter.conversions.time._` and `import com.twitter.util.Await`?

Comment: @RameshMaharjan When I use `map` instead of `foreach` (which doesn't actually clean this up because I still have to load it into `var results: Seq[Result]`, I seem to be only getting the first result before it returns

Comment: @MattFowler Trying `Await.result(resultStream.toSeq(), 1.second)` just times out (it does with longer durations, too) - it's never getting the results but it hang for the duration of the timeout - and yes, those are the libraries I'm using

Comment: @L0ne, I am guessing `mapWithState` should be the best choice to update `results: Seq[Result]` with every `stream`.

Comment: like @MattFowler mentioned - `Await.result(work.toSeq(), 1.second)` seems like the way to go but you say it hangs - are you sure the stream is finite? If it is infinite hanging on waiting for it's values makes sense.

Comment: @Dani Nailed it, thanks. The stream was never terminating

Comment: @L0ne Cool, happy it worked :) Posted the solution as an answer as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like @MattFowler pointed out - you can force the stream and wait until it's complete using:

```
Await.result(resultStream.toSeq, 1.second)
```

`toSeq` will start *realizing* the stream and return a `Future[Seq[A]]` that completes once all the element are resolved, as documentated [here](https://twitter.github.io/util/docs/com/twitter/concurrent/AsyncStream.html#toSeq():com.twitter.util.Future[Seq[A]]).

You can then block until the future completes by using `Await.result`.

**Make sure your stream is finite!** Calling `Await.result(resultStream.toSeq, 1.second)` would hang forever.

Comment: Ultimately, I fixed the stream to be finite, and then `Await.result(resultStream.toSeq)` worked fine